# Private instantiation of generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm a bit new to Java, but I'm really confused as to why these two "equivalent" statements throw different errors:

```
public class SampleArray<T> implements Grid<T> {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    private List<List<T>> grid = new ArrayList<List<T>>();

    public SampleArray(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

This works fine, from understanding it instantiates a class that accepts generic type T and has properties x, y, and a private property List that takes List and T

```
public class SampleArray<T> implements Grid<T> {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    private List<List<T>> grid;

    public SampleArray(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        List<List<T>> this.grid = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    }
}
```

This gives me an error, specifically:

```
Syntax Error insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement;
Syntax Error insert "VariableDelarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration
```

Right next to the angle bracket at `T>> this.grid`. Why am I getting this error? Are they not equivalent just one is being instantiated in different places? The interface Grid is just a generic interface

Comment: That has nothing to do with generics. Doing `int this.x = x;` is invalid Java as well. Why do you think you need to repeat the type of the field when initializing this.grid?

Comment: Wow... i feel so... dumb. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're defining grid in the constructor again. Try this

```
public SampleArray(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.grid = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
}
```

instead. It will declare grid in your class as private field. The initialization is done in the constructor.

The line

```
private List<List<T>> grid = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
```

defines and initializes grid in one turn.

Answer (score 6):

The second piece of code has bad syntax.  You should not re-specify the data type when initializing `this.grid`; the compiler will think you are declaring a local variable, and `this` can't be used in creating a local variable.

Remove the data type on the variable.

```
this.grid = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
```